# When you sit IN AT the controls? Is this correct?

Tags: prepositions

Which form is correct?

> When you sit in at the controls of a plane for the first time, everything changes forever.

Or should I say

> When you sit at the controls of a plane for the first time, everything changes forever.

I'd like to describe my first solo flight.

Comment: You normally sit [***at*** or ***behind** the controls*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+sat+%2A+the+controls&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Che%20sat%20%2A%20the%20controls%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20sat%20at%20the%20controls%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20sat%20behind%20the%20controls%3B%2Cc0) Or [***in** the cockpit*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+sat+%2A+the+cockpit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20sat%20in%20the%20cockpit%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Personally, I would understand the "doubled-up preposition" usage ***sit in at the controls*** as meaning you're not the *primary* pilot - you're just a "passenger / thrill-seeker" who's being allowed to "have a go" at controlling the plane for a short period, with the real pilot telling you exactly what to do, and ready to take over immediately if anything goes wrong. Probably not exactly "legal" in many contexts. *To sit **in on** something* usually means to observe (and perhaps *marginally* participate, but not so fully as other people present - at a business meeting, for example).

Comment: Thank you! So maybe i stick with "After your first solo flight everything changes forever. From this moment on, you will be looking at every airport, every plane and everything that surrounds you from a completely different perspective. A perspective unavailable for most people."

Sounds better?

Comment: Yes. For a ***solo*** flight you definitely don't want that double-up preposition.

Comment: You can easily check what preposition is most common for a given context by searching in NGrams for something like **available * anyone** (where that asterisk functions as a "wild-card").

Comment: _Sit in_ is a phrasal verb meaning "To attend a class, educational presentation, meeting, etc. for one time, as a visitor." ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sit_in)). When we say _sit in a chair_ the _in_ is a preposition, and the verb is ordinary _sit_. When you say _sit in at_ the _in_ cannot be a preposition, and any native speaker would read it as _sit in_, and assume you are talking about a training session that you're observing, or something.